# How to play a tremolo between a rest and a note? (piano sheet)

Tags: sheet-music, tremolo

I'm playing a piano piece that has some tremolo symbols between a rest and a note ("Odeon" by Ernesto Nazareth), and below the symbol there are subtle tiny marks.

Why does this symbol look slightly different?

How should I play this?

[image: "Odeon", Ernesto Nazareth, m. 33]

Comment: Welcome! Can you post a bit more context too, especially enough to see the rhythm of the rest of the measure and the time signature?

Comment: I'll also mention: It's definitely not tremolo. I'm guessing it's a [caesura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesura)—a breath mark, or pause—though it seems a funny place for it.

Comment: I agree with @AndyBonner, with the additional possibility that this is from musescore, and it is a tremolo but placed incorrectly.

Comment: Do you see the faint black dots below the notation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a mistake in the score. Those are supposed to be the beams for two grace notes on B and D#. Below is an image from [the score on IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Odeon_(Nazareth%2C_Ernesto)).

[image: "Odeon", by Ernesto Nazareth, m. 33]

Comment: Fun with OCR, most likely

Comment: These days, it seems like a lot of questions on this site asking "how do I play this notation?" are due to crappy free transcriptions.

Comment: Thanks, @Aaron! That's it! I should have consulted a second score!